# How to integrate Microsoft Graph API for Microsoft Teams App published in Market Place?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to develop an Microsoft Teams app which will use Graph API and publish it to Market Place, all articles I have read suggest this integration require Application Registration on Azure Portal of a specific tenant. However, how can I register the application if the application is published, i.e. not for any specific tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. If you look at the screenshot in this article (just below where [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) will take you), in the screenshot is show "Accounts in this organizational directory only". You want to choose the **OTHER** option: ""Accounts in any organizational directory".

Depending on what your app does, you will need some kind of authorization though, either from the user(s) or from the administrator, in the end-user's tenant.

Comment: great, glad to help